# String subscript out of range. String size is unknown and looping string until null

Tags: c++, string, loops, null, undefined

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string word;
 int j = 0;

 cin >> word;

 while(word[j]){
 cout << "idk";
 j++;
 }
 cout << "nope";



 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

This is just a little trial program to test this loop out.  The program I am working on is about vowels and printing vowels out from a sequence determined by the user.  The string isn't defined until the user types in.  Thank you for your guys help in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for your loop:

```
while(j < word.size()){
  cout << "idk";
  j++;
}
```

Comment: The issue being that string is not a null terminated character array like a C-String. Attempting to call the [] operator beyond the length of the string gives the reported error. For a null terminated character array, use the string::c_str() method

Comment: +1 word.length() would also work, and personally I prefer for loops for situations like this one to a while.

Answer (score 4):

The size of an `std::string` is *not* unknown - you can get it using the `std::string::size()` member function.  Also note that unlike C-strings, the `std::string` class does not have to be null-terminated, so you can't rely on a null-character to terminate a loop.

In fact, it's much nicer to work with `std::string` because you always know the size.  Like all C++ containers, `std::string` also comes with built-in iterators, which allow you to safely loop over each character in the string.  The `std::string::begin()` member function gives you an iterator pointing to the beginning of the string, and the `std::string::end()` function gives you an iterator pointing to one past the last character.

I'd recommend becoming comfortable with C++ iterators.  A typical loop using iterators to process the string might look like:

```
for (std::string::iterator it = word.begin(); it != word.end(); ++it)
{
   // Do something with the current character by dereferencing the iterator
   // 
   *it = std::toupper(*it); // change each character to uppercase, for example
}
```